# Почему начислилось 3 репутации за обычный плюс

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Сейчас вот начислилось 3 очка репутации за обычный плюс, это какое-то особенное поведение системы? Прочитал вроде бы все что выпало на мете по запросу "репутация"  - не нашел ничего такого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это так ограничение на 200 репы в день сработало)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб эм, но стало 320 за день после этого плюса...

Comment: Там ограничение на репутацию именно за голоса за сообщения. Ограничение не действует на репутацию за отмечание ответа верным и, если не ошибаюсь, за конкурсы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, тоесть если мне сегодня еще влепят + то будет 0?

Comment: Ага, всё верно) Но в 3 часа ночи по МСК серверные сутки сменятся и можно будет заново получать репутацию)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, буду знать